# Is it possible to view Cloudformation stack creation errors via CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating Cloudformation stacks with the `aws` cli command.  A change to my Cloudformation template has resulted in all the stacks being rolled back.  Running `aws cloudformation describe-stack-events` does not show the error that caused the rollback.

How can I view stack creation errors with the `aws` cli command?  Or is the web interface required for this?

Comment: Can you double check? The docs clear says that it does: "Success/failure message associated with the resource.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Marcin's comment, the error message will be in `ResourceStatusReason` property. Sample from a failing stack:

````
aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name mystack --max-items 2 --query 'StackEvents[].ResourceStatusReason'                  

[
    "The following resource(s) failed to create: [Cluste123]. ",
    "Replication from cluster in same region is not supported (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 12345; Proxy: null)"```
````